# Spark Gap Circuit Creating Unpredictable Current Spikes, What is Causing This?

Tags: current, transformer, high-voltage, flyback, spike

I have recently been messing around with bug zapper / spark ignitor circuits as a way to learn more about high voltage electronics (This is my first foray into high voltage territory other than a few simple Solid State Relay projects, but I have pretty extensive professional experience with low voltage DC design: https://www.hammerheadaudio.com/designs).

I'm working on modifying a bug zapper circuit for continuous discharge, ie, creating continual loud bright sparks on demand: https://www.instagram.com/p/CDnQEWfFiHX/?utm_source=ig_web_copy_link. I have everything working pretty well and things seem stable (no components burning out, can run sparks continuously), except that I'm getting really unpredictable high current spikes while the circuit is running. When this happens it will be running fine and drawing a steady 2A at 9V from my variable supply, when all of a sudden the current draw will shoot up and throw my supply into overcurrent protection mode. This dips the supply voltage which in turn browns out the microcontroller I'm using to generate a PWM waveform to control my transformer, and I have to power-cycle the whole circuit to restore proper operation. This seems to happen randomly: I can have the sparker activated for as little as 1 second or for up to 30 seconds before it happens, but it happens consistently when I leave the sparker on. This breaks nothing and everything still works once I complete the reset. No components are getting especially hot, and certainly nothing beyond what would be expected through normal operation.

Here is the schematic for what I have on my breadboard. I'm using a PIC18F27Q43 (shown here as block diagram without full pin count for simplicity) to generate a PWM waveform at 26kHZ, 50% duty cycle. I'm translating this to 9V using a 2N3904 transistor in order to drive my IRF640 mosfet and create a 9VAC voltage across the transformer primary. Circuit is activated by closing switch from 9V to transformer pin. Transformer is an Aliexpress part found here: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/33032000591.html?spm=a2g0s.12269583.0.0.56165a16YK0g1W Transformer secondary runs into a voltage multiplier circuit harvested from a battery operated flyswatter racket:

[image: Sparker Schematic]

Can anyone give some advice on what might be causing this? Anything I should modify to prevent this from happening? The interval this occurs at is very unpredictable and it shuts the whole circuit down, so it's pretty hard to debug (I only have access to variable supply, analog scope, and basic volt meter). I also fully realize that a lot of this circuitry might not be best practice, my intention is to use this a learning project so any input on things I could improve is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: C3 may be too large if the holding current of the arc results in a deep discharge at low voltage/current and too much energy being discharged 1/2 CV^2

Comment: What happens if you lower the pulse repetition frequency? Aliexpress is blocked on my computer. Can you provide specs for the transformer?

Comment: Turns ratio: 100 (the turns ratio is not equal to the boost ratio, usually using a flyback structure to achieve a higher boost ratio)
Model: Second generation single-tube flyback driver board
Input voltage: DC (DC) 5V~15V
Input current: <5A
Power: <70W
Frequency: <26kHz
Please note before use: Single-pole flyback topology transformer high-voltage output must pull arc or load, no-load is prohibited! Single-tube type drive board should not work for a long time, if you need to add a fan for a long time or replace a larger radiator!

Comment: Wo/filter on 9V, the RF hash may be triggering the protection, not an actual overcurrent. Otherwise ...does it NOT fail when the spark gap width is set small?  So, only fails if Vout is above a certain kilovolts?  If so, then suspect non-destructive internal arcing in the xfrmr. Or suspect similar arcing in one of the caps.  Buy several, swap 'em in the circuit to see if only some give this failure.  Perhaps observe your device in total darkness, for tell-tale glows of unwanted arcing during the failure.  Me, I'd dunk the coil in oil in my vac chamber, to eliminate all air from the windings.

Comment: @wbeaty I occasionally get arcing in the voltage multiplier circuit (always in areas directly connected to C3), if I position my spark gap too wide. I haven't noticed this having any relationship with the problem I'm getting, but I'll check for it. As for the coil, it's sealed inside a plastic housing, so I don't think air is an issue, or if it is I'm unable to fix it.

Comment: @Tony Stewart Sunnyskyguy EE75

Sorry I'm having a little trouble understanding your comment. You say C3 may be too large, can you explain more about this issue this would create?

Comment: The ESR both in C3 and the spark gap determines the peak current and power dissipated in both parts. If C3 heats up from repetitive arcs 'it may affect performance of the cap and fail. It may be a self-healing PE type.  Not enough details on the BOM and layout.  Is there a lot of EMI that may cause erratic behavior depending on your position and leakage to earth ground or DC ground?

Comment: @EmmettPalaima Ah, I missed the embedding plastic.  To test for problems there, first, never buy just one three-dollar transformer!  Buy several, so if one is at all suspect for causing failures, just swap it out, to see if this changes the failure rate.   Same with capacitors: if the problem is being caused by internal arcing, this might not be visible through opaque epoxy.  So try swapping out each component, to see if the failure either goes away, or suddenly becomes less frequent.